# Azure AD B2C Authenticating in backend web API built with dotnet core 5.0

Tags: azure, .net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I have been unsuccessful trying to authenticate a Azure AD B2C app in dotnet 5.0 microservice webapi.

I referred to the tutorials which refer to the project hosted at: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2.git

In Startup.cs file, under ConfigureServices, I tried the following as per the sample project:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(
                 options =>    {
                      Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                      options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                  },
                  options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);}
           );
```

I get the following error message:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Error: Exception occurred while processing message.

System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://xxxxxx.b2clogin.com/Tenant-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxID/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'
---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://xxxxxx.b2clogin.com/Tenant-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxID/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'. HttpResponseMessage: 'StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', ...
```

I also tried the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
```

This above authentication method returns the login template html page.

Referring to the project which didn't include TenantId in appsettings.json, I got errors complaining about missing TenantId. So now in appsettings.json, I have the following details:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://xxxxxx.b2clogin.com/",
    "ClientId": "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxx",
    "Domain": "xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/",
    "SigninPolicyId":"B2C_1_testsusi",
    "TenantId": "Tenant-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxID"
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

PolicyId is missing from that openId metadata url due to incorrect key name in appsettings.json.

Change the key `SigninPolicyId` to `SignUpSignInPolicyId` in appsettings.json.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application?tabs=visual-studio#add-the-app-settings